# How to update a list in initState() flutter after the api call?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-listview, flutter-state

So I have a Stateful Widget which has a List variable I want to update from the API call. My issue is that the List is empty even after I do the fetchItems() in the initState().

**How can I then update the itemsList with the content of the fetchItems function?**
Isnt the function suppose to update itemsList if I use setState().

```
class _ItemsWidgetState extends State<ItemsWidget> {
        
  List<ItemsModel> itemsList = [];
  void initState(){
    fetchItems();
  }
    
  fetchItems() async {
    final response = await http.get(url);
    
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final fetchedItems = json.decode(response.body);
        for (var item in fetchedItems) {
            ItemsModel item = ItemsModel.fromJson(item);
            setState(() {
                itemsList.add(item);
            });
      }
    } else {
         throw Exception('Failed to load items');
    }
}
```

Comment: As an optimization just call setState once below the `for`, that way you don't rebuild every few miliseconds on each deserialized item.

Comment: Right I can create a temp list inside the function but that still does not answer my question of why is the itemsList not updating after the function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check fetchedItems is a list type.

```
   class _ItemsWidgetState extends State<ItemsWidget> {
            
      List<ItemsModel> itemsList = [];
      void initState(){
        fetchItems();
      }
        
      fetchItems() async {
        final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
        
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            final fetchedItems = jsonDecode(response.body);
            for (var item in fetchedItems) {
                ItemsModel item = ItemsModel.fromJson(item);
                setState(() {
                    itemsList.add(item);
                });
          }
        } else {
             throw Exception('Failed to load items');
        }
    }
```

Comment: So fetchItems is a json object which I am decoding and that's why I do a loop so I can get each object from the json

Comment: Here, the First time it is decoded as a list. Then you just loop it and stored to a list .thats fine. You can just check using Future.deleay(Duration(second : 1)).then({ setState((){itemList.add(item)}) }) .Hope you will understand the concept .

Answer (score 3):

- Avoid calling setState inside loops, call it after your task has done.
- Always call `super.initState` and mark initState as overrided

```dart
class _ItemsWidgetState extends State<ItemsWidget> {
        
  List<ItemsModel> itemsList = [];

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();

    fetchItems();
  }
    
  fetchItems() async {
    final response = await http.get(url);
    
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final fetchedItems = json.decode(response.body);
 
      for (var item in fetchedItems) {
          ItemsModel item = ItemsModel.fromJson(item);

          /// Remove from setState
          itemsList.add(item);
      }
      
      /// Tells to Flutter that now something has changed
      setState(() {});
    } else {
         throw Exception('Failed to load items');
    }
}
```

Comment: So fetchItems is a json object which I am decoding and that's why I do a loop so I can get each object from the json.

Comment: your "json object" is literally a object or a json array object?

Comment: So this is what the api returns, [{"ID":3,"Username":"test","Name":"test","Price":"2"},{"ID":4,"Username":"test","Name":"test2","Price":"3"},{"ID":5,"Username":"test","Name":"test1234","Price":"6",},{"ID":6,"Username":"test","Name":"test1234","Price":"111"}]

Comment: So I guess with that return I can iterate of it no?

Comment: looks ok, so how are you building your UI on your build method? Looks like the error is not in `fetchItems` method

Comment: Also, you can check if your API returns statusCode = 200, because if it returns a different statusCode, the "fetchItems" do nothing except the API call

Comment: It does return a 200 Status. So this is okay. Well I have a bottomnavigator and when click in it it should Build the Widget which is a Scaffold and creates a Listview. The issue is that the itemsList is empty I think. You think is because initState() load before the Build and I have to wait for the fetch items?

Comment: I realize now that you are not calling super.initState. So you need to call it before any code in your initState, I've updated my answer, please double check

Comment: Why is this necessary?